# chromium 89 dumps core: how to revert to 87?

Tags: apt, chromium, 32-bit

Last Sunday (from dpkg.log) chromium-browser was automatically updated (on my 32-bit Acer Travelmate 800 which I use from home during the pandemic) from 87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 to 89.0.4389.82-0ubuntu0.18.04.1.

Any invocation of chromium-browser now ails with "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

I tried to revert to the previous version with sudo apt-get -t '87.0*' install chromium-browser
but I get "E: The value '87.0*' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release
is not available in the sources", ditto if I try with full version number.

Is there a repository from which I can install (and later lock) an older working version of chromium-browser ?
Thanks

Comment: This may help. The official page of the product. https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

Comment: unfortunately not ... it fails at step 6 in the sense that I located 87.0.4280.66  created on November 17, 2020 with base position 812852, but can find no build with such number

Comment: I have same problem
 Chromium-browser i386 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04.5 not opening loading 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1928463

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I think chromium stopped working because it now requires SSE3. I uninstalled the app and downloaded the previous version packages chromium-browser and chromium ffmpeg extra from Ubuntu website and ok now. I used binary build from below.

[https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/20310560](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/20310560)

Comment: Your suggestion was useful to resurrect an apparently running chromium 87. I had to download the deb and use apt install (clicking within my other browser after a while fired a software install GUI which said I had no sudo authority to install, maybe because I do not use gnome but fvwm). Install ffmpeg extra first and chromium-browser next. The removed 89 had also an i8ln or whatever package which does not exist, but should not be necessary.

Comment: Here's the link for the packages for Xenial - https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+sourcepub/11773777/+listing-archive-extra.  I installed `sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb chromium-browser-l10n_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb`

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue with Chromium on Lubuntu 18.04.
I read carefully your advises above, and made several changes in my system to solve problem.

1. I removed non-working Chromium 89 packages:

   ```
   sudo apt remove chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
   ```
2. Downloaded Chromium 87 deb packages from https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/20310560

3. Installed these packages by:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb chromium-chromedriver_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_87.0.4280.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb`
   ```

   Please note, you must `cd` to folder with downloaded packages before `sudo dpkg` command.
4. To prevent new upgrade to non-working builds, I put packages on hold:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
   ```

Chromium is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming chrome and chromium are the same.

https://www.techradar.com/amp/news/google-chrome-will-no-longer-support-some-older-processors

> Starting with Chrome 89 any devices that do not meet the new minimum CPU requirements will no longer attempt to install Chrome, and actually running the software itself will result in a crash. Any devices that will be affected by these changes will start to receive warnings from Chrome 87 notifying users that support for their hardware will be ending shortly.

Comment: I did indeed see the warning popup, but I assumed automatic upgrade will not occur !